# Create custom layout for contextmenu

Tags: android, contextmenu

Can you inflate a custom xml layout for the body of a context menu? Right now I have a context menu working on longpress but I want to make it look better than just a list of text options. I'm using menuinflater right now to inflate a simple xml menu item file. Is there a way to inflate a custom xml layout and use that in place of the text?

Answer (score -2):

If the items you want to show is not too many, I think you can pop up a custom dialog instead.

Comment: Yea I know how to use a dialog. The question is can I do this with a context menu?